# How many gumballs in the jar. 2 errors

Tags: c++

Trying to code a guess how many gumballs in the gumballs jar, kinda thing. There are two problems I keep getting:

1. It's supposed to say if the guess is to high or to low but that only happens when i enter a number over 1000 and it says:

> Enter your guess: 1001
>   Too High!
>
> Too Low!
>
> Enter your guess:

2. If you type a letter or phrase it goes haywire saying:

> Enter your guess:
>   Too High!
>
> Too Low!

but it keeps saying that at about a couple hundred maybe even a thousand times a minute -.-

```
#include<iostream>
#include<ctime>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
     int iGumballs;
     int iUserguess;
     int iGuesses = 0;

    while(true)
    {
           system("CLS");
           cin.clear();
           iGuesses = 0;

    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    iGumballs = rand()%1000+1;
    cout << "How many gumballs are in the gumball jar, you guess!" << endl;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter your guess: ";
    cin>> iUserguess;
    if(iUserguess > iGumballs)
    {
                  cout << "Too High!" << endl << endl;
    }
    if(iUserguess > iGumballs)
    {
                  cout << "Too Low!" << endl << endl;
    }
    iGuesses ++;
}while(iUserguess > iGumballs || iUserguess < iGumballs);
cout << "You guessed the right amount of gumballs! High Five!" << endl << endl;
cout << "You took" << iGuesses << " guesses" << endl << endl;
system("PAUSE");
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: When asking a question about source, you should keep it here so that people can see it and not skip it.  Especially when there's no guarantees that your external link will be up in 3 years.  Apologies for my formatting

Comment: This looks, at first glance, like it might be a homework problem. While there is nothing wrong with asking for help with your homework on this site, please be sure to tag the question as [homework].

Comment: actually it's not homework...it was a tutorial-thing because I'm trying to learn C++ to help out some people on a game called OpenLieroX, it's a pretty fun game but there short on developers, and since I used to do some coding last in QBasic and I had fun with it, I wanted to learn something that wasn't outdated.

Comment: Regarding it going haywire on non-integer input, read http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/input-output.html, sections 15.2 through 15.4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me hint at one problem.  Let's take a look at the two checks you have for printing the message "too high" and "too low":

```
    if(iUserguess > iGumballs)
    if(iUserguess > iGumballs)
```

Notice anything wrong when I put them together?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you post the parts of the code you're having trouble with, instead of just giving us a dump of everything and asking us to figure it out?

Based solely on your description of the problem, I would recommend you:

1. Add input validation (which will solve your second issue)
2. Have another look over the code that checks whether the number is too high/low
3. If you still can't figure it out, post the section of the code that's giving you trouble and explain what you've tried and what went wrong.

Comment: Well I can't really post the part of the code for the second problem because I didn't know what was causing that problem. As you can probably tell by the program type I'm pretty new to C++, so can you explain how input validation works?